# *** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil? I keep getting this error

Tags: ios, navigation, rss

I am working on an app that displays rss feeds in its main view. It has a detail view that shows the web view for that rss feed item. I am adding a slide out navigation bar to the left that will open up. My app keeps crashing when I try to launch it. Here is my code. I am also using a third party library called SWRevealViewController which provides the slide out mechanism.

My MasterViewController.h has one outlet and its for toggling the slide out menu. I declared it as "sidebarButton".

This is my MasterViewController.m

```
#import "JSSMasterViewController.h"
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"
#import "JSSDetailViewController.h"

@interface JSSMasterViewController () {
    NSMutableArray *_objects;
}
@end

@implementation JSSMasterViewController

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    // Change button color
    _sidebarButton.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.96f alpha:0.2f];

    // Set the side bar button action. When it's tapped, it'll show up the sidebar.
    _sidebarButton.target = self.revealViewController;
    _sidebarButton.action = @selector(revealToggle:);

    // Set the gesture
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{
    if (!_objects) {
        _objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [_objects insertObject:[NSDate date] atIndex:0];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _objects.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDate *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [object description];
    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [_objects removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }
}

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

}

@end
```

The Build always succeeds but when the app launches in the iOS simulator it crashes.

The part that seems to get the error is this following code:

```
    - (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{
    if (!_objects) {
        _objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [_objects insertObject:[NSDate date] atIndex:0];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

The place that the breakpoint keeps stopping is:

```
// Set the gesture
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
```

The only error that my console logs is:

```
*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil
```

Is there something that I'm doing wrong here?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: You should add an exception breakpoint to locate which line is causing the error.

Comment: The third block of code that i typed here on this page is where the error is occuring... @rdelmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error message is telling you that `self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer` is nil, which may be caused by `self.revealViewController` being nil.

Comment: How do i make it not nil. Sorry I'm a beginner into iOS.

Comment: You'll have to look at the documentation for `SWRevealViewController` to see how you're supposed to instantiate and initialize the controller.